# What is your default umask set to?

Tags: operating-systems, unix, permissions

What is your default umask set to? Did you run into any problem setting a stricter default umask?

Comment: Tell us more about who the users are and what the security requirements are.  Do the users need to collaborate?  Or are they strangers who should actually be separated by far more than unix file permissions?

Comment: @nealmcb they should be separated by far more than unix file permissions. most of them don't get shell access.

Answer (score 5):

027 on most systems. This gives a default of rw-,r--,--- which is suitable for me. I have seen some environments use 077, but unless the users are very limited in what the can do (so why give them a shell at all?) or experienced it just causes helpdesk/IT issues.

Comment: Linux and some of the BSDs seem to have got this weird thing recently where the default group of each user is named after that user and has no members, so 007 means no-one can read files (by default).